# Equivariant Diffeomorphism $S^2 \times S^3$ to itself with respect to the following $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, group-actions, equivariant-maps

Let $\mathbb{Z}_4$ be the cyclic group generated by $(R,j)$ where $R \in$ SO$(3)$ is the rotation matrix $R = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action on $S^2 \times S^3$ generated by $(x,q) \mapsto (Rx,q\overline{j})$. Here we are thinking of $S^2$ as the standard subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with elements represented as column vectors and $S^3$ as unit quaternions.

> I am looking for an equivariant diffeomorphism $S^2 \times S^3 \rightarrow S^2 \times S^3$ that takes the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action above, and moves the action to the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action generated by $(x,q) \mapsto (x,q\overline{j})$. My issue is that you cannot just use the diffeomorphism $(x,q) \mapsto (R^{T}x,q)$ because $R$ is only being multiplied by the fist coordinate when half of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are acting.

Comment: (quaternions) seems like a better tag than some of the ones I see...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that makes use of the fact that the unit quaterions act by rotations on $S^2$.

Consider $S^2\times S^3$ as a subset of $\mathbb{H}_{im}\times\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}_{im}$ denotes the subspace of purely imaginary quaterions. Note that the unit quaternions act on $\mathbb{H}_{im}$ by conjugation $\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha\beta\alpha^*$, which have the effect of Euclidean rotations. We can choose the identification $\mathbb{R}^3\cong\mathbb{H}_{im}$ so that the matrix $R$ is given by the action of $j$ (since unit imaginary quaterions act by $180^\circ$ rotations). Define a map $f:\mathbb{H}_{im}\times\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}_{im}\times\mathbb{H}$ by
$$
f(\alpha,\beta)=(\beta\alpha\beta^*,\beta)
$$
This map can be smoothy restricted to $S^2\times S^3\subset\mathbb{H}_{im}\times\mathbb{H}$, and has an inverse given by $f^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)=(\beta^*\alpha\beta,\beta)$. Equivariance is straightforward to verify.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't think this action was equivalent to an action on one factor.

Comment: The matrix of conjugation-by-$j$ is ${\rm diag}(-1,1,-1)$. The matrix $R$ is the matrix for conjugation-by-$r$ where $r=(i+j)/\sqrt{2}$. So I don't think your map $f$ is $\Bbb Z_4$-equivariant.

Comment: @runway44 We can't identify $i,j,k$ with the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$; instead we have to choose a different basis containing $r$ and identify $r$ with $j$. One choice of isomorphism $g:\mathbb{H}_{im}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that does this is given by $$g(ai+bj+ck)=\begin{pmatrix}a\\(b-c)/\sqrt{2}\\(b+c)/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$